# Copy excel records between two files into Table formatted rows

Tags: excel, powershell, powerapps, schedule

probably somebody could help me.

I have two excel files and I want to copy (overwrite) data from the source.xlsx into the destination.xlsx
The main problem is, that in the source.xlsx the data are only instered without any formating, but in the destination.xlsx the data are formatted as a table with a name of the table.

I want to schedule with powershell (power automate is too slow for that) the following:

1. Delete all rows from the destination.xlsx (formatted as a table), only the Titles (1st row) can't be delete.
2. Copy all rows (without the Titles - 1st row) from the source xlsx into the destination.xlsx file into the formatted table.

How can I manage it?

I tried the delete the destination.xlsx file and re-create it form the source.xlsx and it looked like it worked, but it wasn't good, because the destination.xlsx file is conntected to one powerapps application and it couldn't be used after the re-creation of the file.

I tried the delete the destination.xlsx file and re-create it form the source.xlsx and it looked like it worked, but it wasn't good, because the destination.xlsx file is conntected to one powerapps application and it couldn't be used after the re-creation of the file.

Comment: You may take a look at the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel).  That could make your life much easier. ;-) ... here you can see how it's used: [ImportExcel PowerShell + Excel = Better Together! with Doug Finke](https://youtu.be/0bR-8b6OMTk)

Answer (score 0):

you may download https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=enlib
and check the sourcecode - there are quite simple functions to export/import csv-xlsx which can help you understand how to work with tables